# How can I run a second user session from windows on my local screen (with Raspberry Pi)?

Tags: linux, windows, remote-desktop

We hav geot only one computer at home that is working with enough power for streaming or other CPU-heavy things. It is down in the living room, so I had the Idea to crate another user session and let it run on my desktop in my room.

I have a reaspberry pi 3 and thought of a remote desktop connection, but that would mean that I connect to the same user that is already running downstairs, wouldn't it? I want to know how to make a remote desktop connecion and to connect to another user session runnign on the comuter dowstairs.

Comment: What are you expecting to do with the PC? RDP imposes some severe limitations on multimedia stuff and the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple users logged into a Windows computer at the same time, each with their own programs running. However, unless you're running a Server edition of Windows, multiple **active** logon sessions are not possible. In other words, you can have a local and remote user both logged on, but only one of them can be active *at the same time*.

So in this case, if you log in user A at the physical computer (console), then log on user B remotely, user A would be disconnected. His programs would still be running, but the console would show a message stating that the computer is in use by user B. If user A unlocks the machine, the opposite would occur, and user B would be disconnected but his programs would remain running in the background.

One alternate approach, if you need multiple interactive logon sessions to the same physical computer, would be to install a virtual machine on the computer and run a second instance of Windows (or other OS if you prefer) and connect to *that* remotely. Of course in the case of using Windows you would need a second OS license.

Server editions of Windows support *Remote Desktop Session Host* which with proper licensing allows for multiple simultaneous interactive logon sessions.

Comment: To clarify how this limit works: The other user will still be logged in and all their programs will continue running. The session is marked as “disconnected” and as such will run completely in the background. So that *may* be enough for the OP...?

Comment: @DanielB you're right, I shouldn't assume. Answer updated to cover that possibility.